# How to convert Powershell to C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll

**Is possible to convert PowerShell code .PS1 to C# code?**

I'v been looking to it on google but I always find the contrary.

[Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) has the [AddIn to convert DLL to PS Code](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReflectorAddinsAndPowerShellLanguageSupportForReflector.aspx), so I think it's possible..

Comment: Why you need this? why dont you call PS code from c#?
Get a quick grasp of this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx

Comment: Because for my company  internal needs, I have  to replicate the code to C#

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll probably have to do a manual port.  I don't know of any tools that can convert Powershell to C#.

Comment: PowerShell is a fairly lax language and C# is quite strict, so it's pretty much a one-way conversion.

Comment: @AndreyIschencko hello B: just to be clear about Andrey's suggestion, you could end up with a C# program that is an EXE like any other C# program.  However your program would just happen to invoke a PS script that was embedded in the C# source code. This wouldn't really be any different than executing SQL or XQuery statements from C#. Programs that execute SQL/XQuery from C# are still considered C# programs (by most people).

Comment: Powershell, though built on .Net, offer a bunch a easing syntax and offers a variety of builtin commands. While most of it may eventually be ported to C#, the nature of the script, the way you wrote it, the PS features you used will influence the amount of work to port the code. And because some PS syntax doesn't exists in C#, I don't believe you'll find a tool to automate it

Answer (score 3):

You can try this Visual studio code extension : PowerShell Pro Tools for VS Code https://ironmansoftware.com/powershell-pro-tools-for-visual-studio-code/

[image]

> Convert between C# and PowerShell code to easily take snippets of either language and convert it to the other. Quickly create P\Invoke functions in PowerShell from C# snippets found on sites like Pinvoke.net.

Comment: The op asked to convert from PS to C#, not from C# to PS

Answer (score 0):

[This open source tool](https://github.com/ironmansoftware/code-conversion) can do it, but the output it generates currently is not great due to the fact that PowerShell is a fairly lax language and C# is quite strict. Powershell also has a lot of commandlet wrapper functions which makes it hard to even make a tool that can really automate this.